# Where can I find some clear examples of static vs. instance "fieldless" properties for use in the classroom?

Tags: c#, .net, static

In all but a few cases, properties are backed up by fields, either explicitly or implicitly. However, properties like `DateTime.Today` are calculated properties not backed up by a field (EDIT: properties like `Guid.Empty` and `Math.E` are backed up by a static field, I'm not interested in those).

In terms of best practice or experience, should such fieldless properties be static, non-static?

I know that opinions vary, so I'd like to find examples either from well known libs, books or from your own experience. Eventually, I hope to find clear examples "from the field" to use in classrooms.

***EDIT:*** I understand the semantics vs implementation discussion, what I'm looking for is real-world examples that explain this concept for each case (static or non-static) clearly and concisely.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you looking for examples? I think that DateTime.Today is probably one of the best examples available.

Comment: That explains one case for static properties. Which explain the other case? I'll edit my q. about "both", because the language disallows that.

Comment: Changed title, hope this takes away some of the unclarity of my q.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Whether a property is static or instance depends on it's purpose and meaning.**

The reason that `DateTime.Today` is static is because it is actually returning an instance of `DateTime` - it would be awkward to first have to create a `DateTime` to then call an instance method (or instance property) to get the current date.

**You should consider making a property static if:**

- It does not represent the state of a particular object instance.
- It is not get written to - or if written to is designed to be thread-safe. (You have to define what thread safe means, of course).
- It is a factory property that is used to return an instance of an object (singleton accessor properties come to mind).
- You don't expect to need an instance property with the same name (C# does not allow duplicate named properties that only differ by whether they are instance vs. static).

Otherwise, the property probably needs to be an instance property - or perhaps a method.

Some interesting examples of static properties in .NET itself include:

- Singleton accessor properties.
- DependencyProperty definitions in WPF
- Globally accessible readonly state, like the Culture instances for formatting strings.

**EDIT:** In thinking about places where instance v. static properties are used in .NET, the Thread class comes to mind as an example of a class that is confusing in its choice of when to use which.

For example, the `CurrentPrincipal` property is a static property while `CurrentCulture` property is an instance property instead. It's unclear if there is any benefit in this organization - it seems (to me) that all of the static properties of `Thread` could have been made instance properties (except `CurrentThread`) without losing any expressive power, but adding consistency and clarity to the public interface.

Comment: (strange, my comment was not submitted). These are excellent points, can you elaborate with a few concrete examples, esp. where instance props are used but statics would've been fine (language-wise) as with `Array.IsReadOnly` (which does not return a field, but a constant and could be static, however I don't consider that a "clear" example).

Comment: I like the vagueness of `Thread` as a good example. It wasn't really what I was after (I was looking for *clear* examples of either), but the opposite, an *unclear* example does help in the discussion in the classroom. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Whether you decide to make a property static or not should be determined by the semantics of that particular property, *not* whether it's backed by a field.

Comment: I understand that difference, sorry if I phrased my q. unclear, see my recent edit. I'm looking for real-world, clear and self-explaining examples.

Answer (score 0):

They can be both according to meaning. Most of DateTime's properties are calculated fields. DateTime is represented by a long and all its properties are calculated based on that value.

Comment: Thanks, but DateTime was used to illustrate the meaning of my question, I'm looking for other and possibly better self-explaining examples

Comment: My point was that some properties have to do with an instance, some are with a type. DateTime.Today is a type example, and myDateTime.Day is an instance property.